How capture the error value for each epoch in MATLAB?
everyone!
I'm having a problem regarding my Deep Learning project, in the image regression task, and I would like to know how I could obtain the RMSE value at each epoch of my model's execution, and export in a .xlsx archive.
rmseValues = zeros(numEpochs, 1);
for epoch = 1:numEpochs
    [net, info] = trainNetwork(XTrain, YTrain, layers, options);
    YPred = predict(net, XTrain);
    rmseValues(epoch) = calculateRMSE(YTrain, YPred);
end
rmseTable = array2table(rmseValues, 'VariableNames', {'RMSE'});
disp(rmseTable)

However, due to the nature of the for loop, training is performed at the same rate as the number of epochs defined. I would therefore like to know if there is a function that allows me, for example, to obtain the array of execution data.
The motivation is that I would like to use this data for another project.
I want to export the data in a .xlsx or .csv archive but I wanna discover the approach to obtain.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

To capture the RMSE value at each epoch during the training process in MATLAB, you can use a custom training loop or modify the training options so that it has custom functions that calculate the RMSE at each epoch.
Using a custom training loow allows you to have control over the training processes. To do this you need to:

Initialize your variables (so you can store your RMSE values)
Train the network manually, updating your network parameters and calculate RMSE
Save your RMSE values to CSV file

Heres an example that I would recommend:
% Initialize variables
numEpochs = 50;  % Define your number of epochs
rmseValues = zeros(numEpochs, 1);

% Custom training loop
for epoch = 1:numEpochs
    % Perform a training step
    [net, info] = trainNetwork(XTrain, YTrain, layers, options);
    
    % Make predictions
    YPred = predict(net, XTrain);
    
    % Calculate RMSE
    rmseValues(epoch) = sqrt(mean((YTrain - YPred).^2));
    
    % Optionally, display the RMSE value for this epoch
    fprintf('Epoch %d: RMSE = %.4f\n', epoch, rmseValues(epoch));
end

% Convert to table and save to .xlsx or .csv
rmseTable = array2table(rmseValues, 'VariableNames', {'RMSE'});
writetable(rmseTable, 'RMSE_per_epoch.xlsx');  % Save as .xlsx
% Alternatively, you can use writetable(rmseTable, 'RMSE_per_epoch.csv'); for CSV

If that isn't your forte or preference, you can use trainingOptions with a custom outputFcn which captures the RMSE. The approach for this is as follows:

Define custom output functions
Set your trainingOptions
Export your data

Heres a coding outline for assistance:
% Initialize a variable to store RMSE values
rmseValues = [];

% Define the custom output function
function stop = myOutputFcn(info)
    global rmseValues;
    if info.State == 'iteration'
        YPred = predict(info.TrainingAccuracy); % Adjust for your needs
        rmse = sqrt(mean((info.TrainingLoss - YPred).^2));  % Replace TrainingLoss with your targets
        rmseValues = [rmseValues; rmse];
    end
    stop = false;  % Continue training
end

% Set training options with custom output function
options = trainingOptions('sgdm', ...
    'MaxEpochs', numEpochs, ...
    'OutputFcn', @myOutputFcn);

% Train the network
net = trainNetwork(XTrain, YTrain, layers, options);

% Export RMSE values to .xlsx or .csv
rmseTable = array2table(rmseValues, 'VariableNames', {'RMSE'});
writetable(rmseTable, 'RMSE_per_epoch.xlsx');  % Save as .xlsx

This approach will log RMSE and export data alike option 1. In my opinion, the first option is the better one and I would recommend you stick to that one.
